# Read register value to variable, with one asm command

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

How can I read register value to variable with one inline assembler command?
I am using gcc on old freeBSD system (v2.1 i386).

I have such code:

```
static volatile unsigned long r_eax, r_ebx;
asm ("movl %%eax, %0\n" :"=r"(r_eax));
asm ("movl %%ebx, %0\n" :"=r"(r_ebx));
```

As result I get this:

```
mov    %eax,%eax
mov    %eax,0x1944b8
mov    0x1944b8,%eax
mov    %ebx,%eax
mov    %eax,0x1944bc
mov    0x1944bc,%eax
```

But i need just:

```
mov    %eax,0x1944b8
mov    %ebx,0x1944bc
```

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does it for me (as long as `r_eax` / `r_ebx` are static)

```
asm ("movl %%eax, %0\n"
     "movl %%ebx, %1\n"
     : "=m"(r_eax), "=m"(r_ebx));
```

Beware that, unless you specify assembly language statements within the *same* `asm()` bracket, the compiler might decide to do all sorts of "interesting optimizations" in-between, including modifications to these regs.

Answer (score 2):

Notice you are using constraints instructing gcc to put the result into a register. So it can not directly put it into memory. Since you only want to store values from registers already there, you don't even need any instructions, just constraints, like so:

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ("" : "=a" (r_eax), "=b" (r_ebx));
```

Comment: You _can_ directly put it into memory, using the `"=m"` constraint, that's what it is for. See my answer.

Comment: @FrankH: what I meant was that by using the =r constraint he explicitly instructed gcc not to put it in memory, therefore he has forbidden the mov to go to memory. "it can not directly put it into memory" = gcc can not, since the programmer said otherwise. Of course using =m would work, I was not debating that.

Comment: Didn't mean to offend, sorry. Just wanted to point out that what asmodan asked for wasn't impossible per se, but just not working for him since he used the wrong constraint.

Comment: @FrankH: I am not offended. I might have been unclear. Both of our solutions are fine, yours is more explicit and controls the movs directly, mine leaves it to the compiler.